# how to use addConstraint and NSLayoutConstraint in objective c

Tags: objective-c, autolayout

I have a two horizontal space constraint in storyboard that take the left and right of view in table cell .

storyboard constraint:

```
 Horizontal Space - Content View - View
```

this is the IBOutlet that connect to this constraint

```
 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *contentViewRightConstraint;
 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *contentViewLeftConstraint;
```

Can I do this in code ?

I found this but I don't know how to work with this.

And where I add this code.

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint 
     constraintWithItem:label
     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
     toItem:self.view
     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
     multiplier:1.0
     constant:0.0]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. The easiest way would be to to it using [`constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:`](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLayoutConstraint/constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:):

```
NSDictionary *views = @{@"firstView" : self.firstView, @"secondView" : self.secondView};
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[firstView]-0-[secondView]" options:0 metrics:0 views: views];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

That will pin first view to the left and make the space between first view and second view 0